# The jquery "on click" function gets triggered on key press "enter"

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".multipleDataRow").on("click", "[id^='multiremove_']", function() { 
        //code here to delete
    });
});
```

I want to avoid remove function from being called on key press "enter"

this on click function is triggering when i focus on other textbox and key press enter button.

the remove button is inside the container having class "multipleDataRow".

The remove function keeps on triggering on key press enter on other fields.

Edit: HTML from coment

```xml
<div class="multipleDataRow">
  <label class="">Skills</label>
  <div class="">
    <div id="" class="">
      <div id="multiRow_2_Skillset" class="mBtm-5 span8 mLft-0">
        <input type="text" placeholder=".." id="skill" name="skills[]" value="" class="m-wrap" readonly="readonly">
        <select name="data[tmp_experiences[]]" id="tmp_years_exp_2" class="m-wrap" disabled="disabled">
          <option value="1">1</option>
        </select> Yrs&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div id="spanMultiremove_Skillset_2" class="mBtm-5">
        <button id="multiremove_Skillset_2" skillset_skexp="59" class="btn mini red"> remove </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- Missing in comment -->
</div> <!-- Missing in comment -->
```

Comment: Is the key press triggering the click event, or is it triggering a button which triggers a click event?  Show your markup.

Comment: Are you pressing enter in a child of `.multipleDataRow` that doesn't have an id starting with `multiremove_` ? And what type of element is that, textarea/input/button?

Comment: yes the key press is triggering the click event which should only happen on "click" event.

Comment: FYI, i'd shove `e` in as a parameter of the click function and inside, check `e.type`

Comment: <div class="multipleDataRow">
<label class="">Skills</label>
<div class="">
<div id="" class="">
<div id="multiRow_2_Skillset" class="mBtm-5 span8 mLft-0">
<input type="text" placeholder=".." id="skill" name="skills[]" value="" class="m-wrap" readonly="readonly">
<select name="data[tmp_experiences[]]" id="tmp_years_exp_2" class="m-wrap" disabled="disabled">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
Yrs&nbsp;
</div>
<div id="spanMultiremove_Skillset_2" class="mBtm-5">
<button id="multiremove_Skillset_2" skillset_skexp="59" class="btn mini red">
remove
</button>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @GeorgeJoffinJoy Please edit your original question and add the HTML markup from your comment there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key whilst focused on a button is treated in the same way as a `click` event by the browser.

As Rory has mentioned, this is a feature by design of all Browsers, if you wish to negate this feature end users may be unhappy with the end result as it will not have all the Standard functionality.

To negate this you could have a check for `onkeydown`/`onkeyup`/`onkeypress` to check whether a keyboard action occurs prior to the click event firing and stop the click events code firing if a key was pressed.

i.e.

```
var isKeyPress = false;

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      isKeyPress = true;
   }
}

jQuery(".multipleDataRow").on("click", "[id^='multiremove_']", function() { 
   if (!isKeyPress) {
      //code here to delete
   }
   isKeyPress = false;
});
```

This should stop the click events code running if the `isKeyPress` value is `true`

Comment: @Nunners - you could have checked for enter keyCode. Your code will stop the click event code execution if any key is pressed once.

Comment: @AlokSwain You are right, I also forgot to add the line `isKeyPress = false;` at the end of the click event handler. I've added a check for the `keyCode` and the missing line.

Comment: @Nunners - thanks for this. Actually googled to find out how to make Enter key act like click event and saw this. Turns out my button was wrapped in an unnecessary anchor tag for some reason so once I removed that all was good

Comment: The problem I find is that the "click" event is triggered by the RETURN "keydown" event.  If I "press" a button using the mouse then the button changes colour on the "mousedown" event but the "click" isn't triggered until the "mouseup".  Similarly if I "press" a button using the spacebar then it changes colour on the "keydown" event but the "click" isn't triggered until the "keyup".  What's so special about RETURN that it triggers the "click" on "keydown"?

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. I have a a click event on a button. I can unfocus from that button, even go as far as `$(button).blur()` as well.. click into my textarea, and press `enter` .. click event still responds.

Comment: Wonderful solution. I love this. <3

Comment: @Trip And the original question was actually the same problem: `this on click function is triggering when i focus on other textbox and key press enter button`

Answer (score 4):

This is by design of all browsers. It's an accessibility feature, and should therefore not be tampered with.

If it is causing unintended behaviour in your site, change your HTML markup to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write code in your html code like for your html tag

```
onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);"
```

This will prevent click event by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people seemed to have missed this part:

> this on click function is triggering when i focus on other textbox and key press enter button.

That's only standard browser behavior when the input and and button are *in a form*.  That may be the case for you outside the snippet provided, but that was definitely the case for me.

I just changed the `<form>` tag to a div, because the logic was all handled via jQuery anyway.  But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56398344/3499424) also had a helpful nugget:

> ...the default type of a `<button>` element is `"submit".` This means that if you press Enter anywhere in the `<form>` containing this button, it will automatically submit.
>
> TLDR: add type="button" to your button element.